# Increment a running total of player 1 and 2 locations in python 3

Tags: python, variables, global

I have the following code which works perfectly except for the last bit which is to get the running totals for the player1 and player2 locations working correctly. Currently, it resets the total for player1, so it never stores a running total, and player2 doesn't seem to update at all. I would appreciate suggestions on a) how to fix this error b) explanations on the most efficient ways to approach this, including a note on global/local variables and their use. Have I used them correctly?

The code is:

```
    def callmatrix(player1,player2, n):
    print("*************LOADING GAME******************")
    print("Welcome:", player1,"and", player2)
    for i in matrix(n):
            print(i)
    playing = True
    global player1position
    player1position = 0
    player2position=0
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing,player1position,player2position)


def playerturns(player1,player2,playing,player1position,player2position):
   print("Player1 Matrix Position is: ", player1position)
    print("Player 2 Matrix Position is: ", player2position)
    print(" - - - - - - - - - - ")
    print("Press Enter to continue")

    while(playing):     
        roll=input()
        if roll=="":
            RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2,player1position,player2position)

        else:
            break
    RollTwoDiceP2(player1,player2,player1position,player2position)


global player1position
def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2,player1position,player2position):
    turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    roll=die1+die2    
    print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
    playing = False
    matrixlist=matrix(7)
    print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......",matrixlist[6][0]+roll)
    player1position=matrixlist[6][0]+roll
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing,player1position,player2position)

global player2position
def RollTwoDiceP2(player1,player2,player1position,player2position):
    turn=input("Player 2, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    roll=die1+die2    
    print("Player2: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
    playing = True
    matrixlist=matrix(7)
    print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......",matrixlist[6][0]+roll)
    player2position==matrixlist[6][0]+roll
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing,player1position,player2position)
```

The bit that seeks to hold a "running total" of the player's position on the matrix is:

```
player2position==matrixlist[6][0]+roll
```

The matrix, for reference is generated as follows:

```
[43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The output, that does not quite work as it should is:

```
Player1 Matrix Position is:  0
Player 2 Matrix Position is:  0
 - - - - - - - - - - 
Press Enter to continue

Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>r
Player1: You rolled a: 3 and a 5 which gives you a: 8
You have moved 8 spaces to position:....... 9
Player1 Matrix Position is:  9
Player 2 Matrix Position is:  0
Press Enter to continue
Player 2, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>r
Player2: You rolled a: 2 and a 3 which gives you a: 5
You have moved 5 spaces to position:....... 6
Player1 Matrix Position is:  9
Player 2 Matrix Position is:  0
```

---

```
Press Enter to continue

Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>r
Player1: You rolled a: 4 and a 6 which gives you a: 10
You have moved 10 spaces to position:....... 11
Player1 Matrix Position is:  11
Player 2 Matrix Position is:  0
 - - - - - - - - - - 
Press Enter to continue
Player 2, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>
```

and so on....

Any suggestions/answers and explanations appreciated.

UPDATE:

I did try adding the global command inside one of the subs in case that was the problem as so:

```
    global player1position
def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2,player1position,player2position):
        turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
        die1=random.randint(1,6)
        die2=random.randint(1,6)
        roll=die1+die2    
        print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
        playing = False
        matrixlist=matrix(7)
        print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......",matrixlist[6][0]+roll)
        global player1position
        player1position=matrixlist[6][0]+roll
        playerturns(player1,player2,playing,player1position,player2position)
```

However, the error (that doesn't allow the program to execute at all) is:

```
"Name player1position is parameter and global"
```

UDPATE: I posted an answer below, but am still hazy on global variables and if I am using them correctly. I am happy to select an ANSWER, for someone who can explain

a) Based on my answer (see below) I am still getting this error:

```
SyntaxWarning: name 'player2position' is used prior to global declaration
```

b) Best practice with global variables in reference of my code. How should I be doing this and tightening up that sub to make it work correctly/more elegant

Comment: Not entirely solving your problems but `player2position==matrixlist[6][0]+roll` does not update any anything. `==` is testing if player2position and matrixlist[6][0]+roll are equal or not

Comment: If `player1position` is global then it cannot be a parameter, so you'll have to remove it from the list of parameters. You'll likely have to do the same for player2, and end up declaring your functions as `def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2)`.

Comment: Both helpful comments, but don't solve the problem or suggest ways in which a running total could then be implemented

Comment: @bouletta - yes, player2position==2 was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned in the comments you shouldn't pass global variables as parameters. That being said I believe what you are looking for is :

```
player2position += roll
```

which is equivalent to

```
player2position = player2position + roll
```

you should also initialize `player2position` to `matrix[6][0]`

The reason it was reset for player 1 is that you were never using the current position. You were always adding the roll to `matrix[6][0]` which if I understood your example correctly is always 1. 
For player 2 as I mentioned comment you were merely comparing values.

As a side note you may notice that your code for both players is identical. You may want to write a single `RollTwoDice(player)` method and then call that method once for each player.

EDIT : Considering the answer you provided I take it you want the initial position to be 0 and not 1 (or `matrix[6][0]`) therefore you should initialize `player2position` to 0. However I'm not sure I understand why you use a matrix at all here if your position is just a number

Comment: do you initialise inside or outside the function - see below. It works, but i get the error: player1position and player2position have been used prior to global declaration ....

Comment: See my update. I am happy to select answers for someone who can explain the error in my answer (it still works though) and suggest/explain a cleaner way of declaring and using the variables player1position and player2position

Comment: In all honesty, I would do a class and forget about global variables. Implement a class game or something containing all your methods and have player1position and player2positions be attributes. You can them initialize them to 0 in the __init__ method of the class which will be called when instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that works for me:

```
    player1position=0
def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2):
    #print("player1position at stat of RollTwoDicep1", player1position) #a test that prints the current value of player 1 position
    turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    roll=die1+die2    
    print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
    playing = False
    matrixlist=matrix(7)
    print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......",matrixlist[6][0]+(roll+player1position))
    global player1position
    #print("playerposition plus roll:", player1position+roll) #a test that prints the playerposition+roll - this always comes up to 1 more than it should do on the location, so below substract 1, to make it produce an accurate location on the matrix for a particular roll
    player1position=matrixlist[6][0]+(roll+player1position)-1
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)
```

The problem was that the code needed to ADD roll+playerposition1 to increment the running total of the location on the grid for player1.

The second problem was that the code didn't account for the fact that 1 needed to be subtracted from roll+player1position to accurately locate the correct position on the matrix

Finally, I needed to remove the parameters and correctly use global variables inside the function for the player1 and player2 positions.

Code for only the player1position, which now works, shown above.

UPDATE:

The code above did work, but came up with a WARNING regarding the use of global variables.

I changed it to the below, and it does work without any warnings or errors:

```
    global player1position #declare a local variable called player1position
player1position=0 #set the global variable before the start of this sub to 0
def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2):
    #print("player1position at stat of RollTwoDicep1", player1position) #a test that prints the current value of player 1 position
    turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    roll=die1+die2    
    print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
    playing = False
    matrixlist=matrix(7)
    global player1position
    print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......",matrixlist[6][0]+(roll+player1position))
    #print("playerposition plus roll:", player1position+roll) #a test that prints the playerposition+roll - this always comes up to 1 more than it should do on the location, so below substract 1, to make it produce an accurate location on the matrix for a particular roll

    player1position=matrixlist[6][0]+(roll+player1position)-1
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)
```

Comment: but you never actually update your matrixlist do you? isn't matrixlist[6][0] always 1?

Comment: Yes, that is the starting position, But it is in fact updated by the line player1position=matrixlist[6][0]+(roll+player1position)-1. I am therefore adding the roll to the player1position (running total) rather than to the matrixlist[6][0] ....